# Relations between model class and returning data via LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, rest, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm building REST API server side and I have a problem with fetching data from a database by LINQ. I don't know if my model classes and relations are built in proper way but I can't get data from database by LINQ query.

I'm using .NET core (.NETCoreApp 1.1).

My Model:

User class :

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int IDUser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AvatarPath { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public List<AccessCard> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

AccessCard class :

```
public class AccessCard
{
    [Key]
    public int IDAccessCard { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public User AddedBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

DBcontext class :

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AccessCard>()
            .HasOne(i => i.User).WithMany(u => u.Cards);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<AccessCard> AccessCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

UsersController class :

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly DBContext _context;

    #region CONSTRUCTOR

    public UsersController(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    #endregion

    #region HTTP GET

    // GET: api/users
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers(string cardNr)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cardNr))
        {
            var users = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();

            if (users.Any())
            {
                return Json(users);
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Cards.Exists(c => c.CardNumber.Equals(cardNr)));

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return new ObjectResult(user);
            }
        }
    }

    //GET: api/users/1
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByID(Int32 id)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.IDUser == id);


        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return new ObjectResult(user);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I bulit my database with EntityFramework core with code first approach. I used Package Manager Console to utilize `Add-Migration` and then `Update-Database` commands to create the database. Migrations created successfully my DB. Database server is local MS SQL-Server.

What I want to do is to get Users by its AccessCard number. So I'm trying this in the browser :
GET api/users?cardnr=qwe 
which dosn't return me anything .... I added manually Users and AccessCards to database with correct foreign keys so Users in my DB has some AccessCards on 100%. Parameter `string cardNr`in my `GetUsers` method correctly gets populated with value (qwe e.g.).

[image]
[image]

When I use this :

GET api/users

GET api/users/1

GET api/accesscards

API successfully returns me data so my controller works correctly. I get recpectively all Users, User by ID, all AccessCards.

When I try to debug the UsersController and I set a trap on `var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Cards.Exists(c => c.CardNumber.Equals(cardNr)));` line the code just keep exit from the method and doesn't return me anything.

I don't know if my relation between model classes is built correctly. Is this get the job done correctly ? : 
`modelBuilder.Entity<AccessCard>()
                .HasOne(i => i.User).WithMany(u => u.Cards);`
Do I have to add anything else to by DBcontext class to establish correct relation between User and AccessCard classes ? Basically `public List<AccessCard> Cards { get; set; }` collection should return all AccessCards for a given User in my case.

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: UserIDUser column in AccessCards is optional?

Comment: Hi. Well actually this column appeared when I created the database so I suppose it is a result of a `modelBuilder.Entity<AccessCard>().HasOne(i => i.User).WithMany(u => u.Cards);` code line in `DBContext ` class. I believe it's an evidence that the relation between User and AccessCard works. In some way at least ...I still don't know why I can't get my User by its `cardnr` in this line `var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Cards.Exists(c => c.CardNumber.Equals(cardNr)));`

Comment: Instead of using `Exists` try `Any`.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/9295
Seems like Exists is not translated to server but Any is.

Comment: @Smit you were right. That simply works. Thanks